# Is this a good counterexample?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal B)$, and let $f_1, f_2, f_3, \ldots$ be real-valued measurable functions on $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $g$ be continuous on  $\mathbb{R}$

If $f_n \to f$ in measure, then I understand that $gf_n \to gf$ on $[a,b]$

Here is where I have an issue. Why is this not true for the infinite case, like for $[a,b] = [0,\infty)$? Can someone please provide a counterexample.

*edit:*

should I consider $f_n(x)= \chi_{[n,\infty)}$ then $f_n$ converge to $1$ in measure on $[0,k]$, but why doesn't it converge globally?

Comment: should I consider $f_n(x)= \chi_{[n,\infty)}$, then it converges to $1$ in measure on $[0, k]$ for finite $k$, but why doesn't it converge for $[0, \infty)$

Comment: I think that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\chi_{[n,\infty)}(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, no?

Comment: Can't you simply use a sequence of constant functions $f_n(x)=1/n$ on $[0,\infty)$, and then $g(x)=x$. We have $f_n\to0$ in measure, but $(gf_n)(x)>1$ on $[n,\infty)$, a set of infinite measure.

Comment: @C.Master: I think the first statement is false. Consider the function $g(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$ and $f_n$ the typewriter sequence (which converges to $0$ in measure). $gf_n$ does not converge to $fg=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counter-examples: Take $f_n(x)=\frac 1 x$ for $n<x<n+1$, $0$ for all other $x$. Let $g(x)=x$. Then $f_n \to 0$ in measure but $(n,n+1) \subseteq \{x: f_n(x)g(x) >\frac 1  2\}$ so $m(\{x: f_n(x)g(x) >\frac 1  2\})$ does not tend to $0$.